# String to Int with swift 5

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, int, converters

I have an error message : 
Cannot use instance member 'rni' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
    @Published var rni = ""  
    var revenuNetImposableSaisi = (rni as NSString).integerValue
```

Comment: You can't initialize one property using another outside of `init`

Comment: @NewDev You can declare your var as lazy. **A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used**

Comment: @LeoDabus - true, but didn't want to overcomplicate.. the original question was about string to int conversion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the property before container is initialized. Instead do the conversion at the place of using the `rni`.

Also, Use the `Int` initializer, to convert from `string` to `integer`:

```swift
let string = "123"
let integer = Int(string)
```